# Getting Orchard fields from different parts

Tags: orchardcms

In an Orchard summary view I'm displaying a content item that could be a Page, a Blog Post or a Projection.

I've attached a Media Picker field to all these types and called it Picture.

I'm currently using this horrible bit of code to access the media picker from the content item:

```
if (contentItem != null)
{
    try
    {
        mediaPicker = (MediaLibraryPickerField) contentItem.Blog.Picture;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    if (mediaPicker == null)
    {
        try
        {
            mediaPicker = (MediaLibraryPickerField)
                            contentItem.Page.Picture;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    if(mediaPicker == null)
    {
        try
        {
            mediaPicker = (MediaLibraryPickerField) contentItem.ProjectionPage.Picture;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

There must be a better way?

Comment: I don't reckon there is ^_^

Comment: Really? Bugger! I thought it'd be something obvious that made me feel stupid when I saw it.

Comment: The code isn't too bad. Do you need to access the picker field directly? Or can you use placements to just display it? Or you could attach your field to a part and then access the data from the parts driver and send it to your display. Something along those lines

Comment: Code gets worse every time I need to add a new contentItem type. I could pass the content item to @Display(contentItem), but I'd have to add something to its alternates collection so I could template it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is using Linq:

```
var mediaPicker = (MediaLibraryPickerField)
                 (from part in ((ContentItem)contentItem).Parts
                  from field in part.Fields
                  where field.Name == "Picture"
                  select field).FirstOrDefault();
```

It's clean, and works for future new types that have a Picture field.

Here's the fluent eqivalent:

```
var mediaPicker = (MediaLibraryPickerField)
            ((IEnumerable<ContentPart>)contentItem.Parts)
            .SelectMany(p => p.Fields)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Picture");
```

Comment: I think I made a typo and updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Your typo correction fixed it. I just added a typecast to MediaLibraryPickerField, which was required in my code so the rest of it worked. I also added the fluent equivalent as I prefer that. I added to your answer. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Cool! Yes, perfectly fine by me.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the item to dynamic and access the fields as you do on templates

```
dynamic content = (dynamic)contentItem;
var mediaPicker = content.BlogPart.Picture;
```

Now you have the field on mediaPicker. One disadvantage is that you lose IntelliSense. If the field does not exists I think that mediaPicker is null.

Comment: That only works if it's a blog. What about pages and projections?

Comment: I think that content.ProjectionPart.Picture and content.PagePart.Picture should work.

Comment: They do, but they throw an error if they're not present. Hence all my try catch shenanigans.

Comment: Same problem then. Maybe you can check the content type at the beginning, so you can avoid the try catches.